# How to put "BufferedReader Line into ArrayList"

Tags: java, string, arraylist, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am setting up a class (see below) that creates a playlist based on a string that was returned from a urlConnectReader.

I am attempting to use a BufferedReader to read each line of the string which works fine by itself.

I get an error when I try to add the current line from the BufferedReader to an ArrayList.

My project keeps returning null but when I remove the ArrayList from the function below it shows each line from the string how I want it in my info.logger but I need this to appear in an ArrayList.

```
public class Playlist {

    String output = "'";
    ArrayList<String> contents;
    //String[] content = new String[10];

    public Playlist(String output)  {
        // Sets url data to the content string
        this.output = output;

    }
    //Converts String to ArrayList
    public ArrayList<String> addContentToArray(String output) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        try {

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                contents.add(line);

            }} catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Uh Oh, array is empty");

            }
        return contents;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(contents);
    }

}
```

I am trying to covert each line of the following String into an ArrayList:

EXTM3U

EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=232370,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d4015"
gear1/prog_index.m3u8

EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=649879,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d401e"
gear2/prog_index.m3u8

EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=991714,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d401e"
gear3/prog_index.m3u8

EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1927833,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d401f"
gear4/prog_index.m3u8"

Without the ArrayList in the function it will work ???

Comment: Your code throws a NullPointerException because you never initialize the list. But this exception is caught by your uber catch block, which catches exceptions that it shouldn't catch, and hides the actual cause by printing "Uh Oh, array is empty", which is wrong, and goes unnoticed. Don't catch Exception. Catch IOException and retrhow it using `throw new UncheckedIOException(e);`. And of course, initialize your list.

Comment: 1-`contents` is not being initialized; 2-adding is commented out;3-Exceptions trace is not being printed (`e.printStackTrace()`);4-would be nice to know WHAT error you are getting;5-see comment from JB Nizet(;6-indentation is *weird*)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger it was initially commented out for testing purposes thanks for putting that out though. I don't  want other people to think that I was running it commented out.

Comment: I just noticed that your method alredy throws IOException. So just remove your try and the catch block completely.

Comment: @JBNizet how do I initialize an empty ArrayList? I don't have any elements to add to it until the BufferedReader checks the lines of the string.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--

Comment: @JBNizet if I remove the try/catch would that make my program crash? I don't want it to explode on errors but display a message and keep running

Comment: There is no way you can have an IOException by running from a String in memory. And your method **already** declares that it can throw IOException. So all your ctch block is doing is to hide the NullPointerException caused by a bug in your code, preventing you from identifying what the problem is. Exceptions being thrown are a **good** thing.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks so much that helped me ! Is there a way I can be friend you on here in case I need future help?

Comment: No, that doesn't exist here. Just ask your question, respecting the rules, and someone will answer.